# Mysql shows an error after trying to run an update request

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-update, syntax-error

as i try to run the update request on mysql for the goal of updating an article mysql shows an error that the request exceeded the maximum length the error is "linting is disabled for this query because it exceeds the maximum length"

Comment: Thanks for sharing the status report. Was there a *question*?

Comment: Please show the update query you're trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for phpMyAdmin reveals the source of the message text ...

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/libraries/classes/Linter.php

```
/**
 * Runs the linting process.
 *
 * @param string $query The query to be checked.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public static function lint($query)
{
    // Disabling lint for huge queries to save some resources.
    if (/*overload*/mb_strlen($query) > 10000) {
        return array(
            array(
                'message' => __(
                    'Linting is disabled for this query because it exceeds the '
                    . 'maximum length.'
                ),
                'fromLine' => 0,
                'fromColumn' => 0,
                'toLine' => 0,
                'toColumn' => 0,
                'severity' => 'warning',
            )
        );
    }
```